# Expand the dimensions of a panel dynamically and enable scroll effect when the shapes are drawn over it.c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, window, drawing, panel

I am trying to draw rectangles on panel of c# window form by taking the width,height and the number of rows and columns of it dynamically from user and they are drawn.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is when the dimensions(width and height) and the number of rows and columns or simply more rectangles are drawn over the panel they are not drawn as the panel doesn't automatically extends to make space for the more shapes so they are missed and I have added the scroll effect to vertical and horizontal but they both aren't working. Thanks.

**WORKING APPLICATION**

So if the rectangles are drawn at the specified width and height then its showing correct drawing. Look at this:

[image]

Now look this its drawn correctly on pressing draw rectangle button:

[image]

But notice when the dimensions are not coming in the physical available window size drawings are missing

Like this input:

[image]

And this is the output missing the drawings a problem must show the drawings when we scroll. But:

[image]

```
//This is the form 1 code 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace ProjectAhmadMalakh
{
    

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int SetValueForWidth = 0;
        public static int SetValueForHeight = 0;
        public static int SetValueForNumberOfRows = 0;
        public static int SetValueForNumberOfCols = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        int h = 0;
        int v = 0;
        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           

            string width = textBox1.Text;
            string height = textBox2.Text;
            
            try
            {
               h  = Int32.Parse(width);
               v = Int32.Parse(height);
               rows = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
               cols = Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text);
               SetValueForWidth = h;
               SetValueForHeight = v;
               SetValueForNumberOfRows = rows;
               SetValueForNumberOfCols = cols;
            }
            catch (FormatException f)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
            }
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the form2 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectAhmadMalakh
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

           

       
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            int h=Form1.SetValueForWidth;
            int v=Form1.SetValueForHeight;

            

            int wd = 0;
            int hd = 0;
            int max = 0;
            Graphics l = e.Graphics;
            string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the height of box for the row: "+0,
                       "Define your height of this row boxes",
                       "0",
                       50,
                       50);
            v = Int32.Parse(input);
            if (v > max)
            { max = v; }
            else { max = 0; }
            int rowCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (Form1.SetValueForNumberOfRows*Form1.SetValueForNumberOfCols); i++)
            {
                rowCounter++;
                if (wd == (h * Form1.SetValueForNumberOfRows))
                {
                    hd = hd + v;
                    wd = wd - (h * Form1.SetValueForNumberOfRows);
                    input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the height of box for the row: " + rowCounter,
                       "Define your height of this row boxes",
                       "0",
                       500,
                       500);
                    v = Int32.Parse(input);
                    if (v > max)
                    { max = v; }
                    else { max = 0; }
                } 
                l.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(wd, hd, h, v));
                wd = wd + h;
                
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int w = Form1.SetValueForWidth;
            int h = Form1.SetValueForHeight;
            int area = w * h;
            label4.Text = w.ToString();
            label5.Text = h.ToString();
            label6.Text = area.ToString();
        }

        private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in c# Window Forms. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your contribution towards solving the problem.

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: @Jimi Oh sorry Ya I forgot

Comment: @Jimi Please check now I have posted the code.Thanks

Comment: Make your Form2 (and, possibly, use meaningful names for your Controls) AutoScroll. The Panel, the surface where the drawing is performed, can be sized based on the dimensions of your grid, triggering the Form's Scrollbars. You don't need to worry about the drawing locations anymore. Remove all those InputBoxes from Paint handler: what are you asking to enter there, for each Paint event and in a loop from `0` to `Form1.SetValueForNumberOfRows*Form1.SetValueForNumberOfCols`? BTW, avoid static Fields. Pass to Form2 a class object that contains all the dimensions needed for the drawing.

Comment: Replace all `Parse()` methods with `TryParse()` (in Form1; you don't need any of these in Form2, especially in a Paint handler)

Comment: @Jimmy.Thanks Jimmy But does this will help in solving the problem because previously I simply harcoded the values and the same result was obtained and there was not the output I was expecting.

Comment: @Jimmy The TryParse is giving me the error.Its not compiling.

Comment: I don't know what you did before. The point is, make your Form perform the scrolling, while you expand your drawing surface (the Panel) to contain the grid, setting the dimensions specified in Form1. That's all. TryParse() is just, e.g., `if (!int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out SetValueForNumberOfRows)) { MessageBox.Show("Bad Rows value"); textBox3.Focus(); return; }`. After that, if the value entered parses to an `int`, `SetValueForNumberOfRows` contains the value. If it doesn't compile, you did something wrong.

Comment: @Jimmy please can you explain the mistake I've made all the code I have shown here.Thanks